# Cordova plugins became undefined after restoring application

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I'm working on html5/css3 application based on angularjs. And building this into android application using cordova 3.5.0.
Everything works fine until I hide application using 'home' button on the phone and then restore it: after that whole app reloads, and plugins became undefined.

Any ideas why this happening and how to fix it? Maybe I need to clarify something about project structure?

I wanted to try calling plugins using cordova .exec() but this method is undefined as well.

Comment: Maybe try to modify platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml to change the launchmode : `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I've figured out the problem by myself, but I think it should've helped as well, but I wasn't been able to modify AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out what's the problem and I feel really stupid right now.
There is an option in dev options: "Don't keep activities", I was testing application on my co-worker's device and this option was turned on(I believe it turned off by default), so it was the root of a problem.